# File sharing solution with approval workflow

Tags: data-leakage, file-upload, file-access

Is there any solution out anyone is aware of that does secure file sharing but with the facility of an approval workflow. A case being a person can upload a file to the secure file sharing solution but requires an approval to actually be added to his account in the secure file sharing solution?
I checked a lot of enterprise solutions (owncloud, pydio, accellion, egnyte, etc) for secure file sharing and I haven't come across any that has a approval workflow when a file is uploaded in it.

We need to grant a facility to administrators to transfer files from their administration system to regular systems. The administration system has access to servers. As of now they are copying files through SMB which cannot be tracked and also poses a concern for data leakage.

Administrators do need to sometimes copy files to servers (scripts, etc) and also from servers (logs, etc). We need this copying, whenever there is a need, to be approved by their supervisor.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any reason not to use SFTP?

Comment: Didn't find any with approval workflow? You know of any?

Comment: If you add private-public keys then only the person with the key will be able to upload files